# Initialize a vector<vector<vector<double> > > in C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have a vector of vector of vector of doubles. I'm trying to initialize it. The below code seg faults. Including the commented code also does not help (does not compile).

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > Q(MAX_GRID);
for(int row = 0; row < MAX_GRID; row++) {
    //vector<vector<double> > inQ(MAX_GRID);
    //Q[row].push_back(inQ);
    for(int col = 0; col < MAX_GRID; col++)
        for(int action = 0; action <= 3; action++)
            Q[row][col].push_back(0);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > Q(MAX_GRID);
```

to

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > Q(MAX_GRID, vector<vector<double> >(MAX_GRID));
```

Otherwise the second dimension consists of empty vectors.

You can do the same thing with the third dimension, avoiding the loop altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) I suggest something like:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 4>, MAX_GRID>, MAX_GRID> Q;
```

No other initialization needed.